# In python, what is a good way to match expected values to real values?

Tags: python, numpy, classification

Given a Dictionary with ideal x,y locations, I have a list of unordered real x,y locations that are close to the ideal locations and I need to classify them to the corresponding ideal location dictionary key.  Sometimes, I get no data at all (0,0) for a given location.
An example dataset is:

```
idealLoc= {1:(907,1026),
           2:(892,1152),
           3:(921,1364),
           4:(969,1020),
           5:(949,1220),
           6:(951,1404),
   'No_Data':(0,0)}

realLoc = [[  892.,  1152.],
           [  969.,  1021.],
           [  906.,  1026.],
           [  949.,  1220.],
           [  951.,  1404.],
           [    0.,     0.]]
```

The output would be a new dictionary with the real locations assigned to the correct dictionary key from `idealLoc`.  I have considered the brute force approach (scan the whole list n times for each best match), but I was wondering if there is a more elegant/efficient way?

Edit: Below is the "brute" force method

```
Dest = {}
dp = 6
for (y,x) in realLoc:
    for key, (r,c) in idealLoc.items():   
        if x > c-dp and x < c+dp and y > r-dp and y < r+dp:
            Dest[key] = [y,x]
            break
```

Comment: Have you looked into [itertools.starmap](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.starmap)? It won't be fast, but you could write the mapping function to compute distance between the real and ideal coordinates and return the key of the closest ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[K-d trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree) are an efficient way to partition data in order to perform fast nearest-neighbour searches. You can use [`scipy.spatial.cKDTree`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html) to solve your problem like this:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree

# convert inputs to numpy arrays
ilabels, ilocs = (np.array(vv) for vv in zip(*idealLoc.iteritems()))
rlocs = np.array(realLoc)

# construct a K-d tree that partitions the "ideal" points
tree = cKDTree(ilocs)

# query the tree with the real coordinates to find the nearest "ideal" neigbour
# for each "real" point
dist, idx = tree.query(rlocs, k=1)

# get the corresponding labels and coordinates
print(ilabels[idx])
# ['2' '4' '1' '5' '6' 'No_Data']

print(ilocs[idx])
# [[ 892 1152]
#  [ 969 1020]
#  [ 907 1026]
#  [ 949 1220]
#  [ 951 1404]
#  [   0    0]]
```

By default `cKDTree` uses the Euclidean norm as the distance metric, but you could also specify the Manhattan norm, max norm etc. by passing the `p=` keyword argument to `tree.query()`.

There is also the [`scipy.interpolate.NearestNDInterpolator`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.NearestNDInterpolator.html) class, which is basically just a convenience wrapper around `scipy.spatial.cKDTree`.

Comment: Thanks Ali.  I ran this code on a slightly larger array it didn't work for me...I got the following results: ilabels[idx]= [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1] and ilocs[idx]=[[ 907 1026]
 [ 907 1026]
 [ 907 1026]
 [ 907 1026]
 [ 907 1026]
 [ 907 1026]
 [ 907 1026]
 [ 907 1026]
 [ 907 1026]
 [ 907 1026]
 [ 907 1026]
 [ 907 1026]
 [ 907 1026]
 [ 907 1026]
 [ 907 1026]]

Comment: Well, what does your input data look like? That's a totally legitimate result in the case where every "real" input point is closer to `(907, 1026)` than any other "ideal" point.

Comment: In fact, probably what's happening is that `{1:(907, 1026)}` is the closest "ideal" location to `(0, 0)`, so in every case where you have no data and query with `(0, 0)` then you will match point #1. You might want to add something like this to your `idealloc` dictionary: `{"no_data":(0, 0)}` to handle such cases.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to use euclidean distance, you can use [`scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.cdist) to calculate the distance matrix and then choose the nearest point.

```
import numpy
from scipy.spatial import distance

ideal = numpy.array(idealloc.values())
real = numpy.array(realloc)

dist = distance.cdist(ideal, real)

nearest_indexes = dist.argmin(axis=0)
```